# How can I get a lme4::glmer to run

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I have this csv file

| Name | ID | Year | Tourist | Feed.bout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anubis | 1 | 2014 | TRUE | 0:01:17 |
| Athena | 2 | 2014 | FALSE | 0:01:53 |

I am trying to run a general linear mixed model with lme4 but I am struggling to get it to run.

My code is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(lattice)

Feedbout=read.csv("Av_Fe_Bout3.csv")
head(Feedbout)

Feedbout$Tourist=as.logical(Feedbout$Tourist)
Av_Fe_Bout3 <- glmer(Feed.bout ~ Year + Tourist + Year:Tourist + (1|ID), family = poisson, data = Feedbout)
summary(Av_Fe_Bout3)
```

and I keep getting

```
Error in mkRespMod(fr, family = family) : 
  response must be numeric or factor
In addition: Warning message:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

I have tried it without a family and also with binomial.

If I change anything else  the `Feed.bout` changes to `NA`s and I don’t know how to change it back.

I think the problem is with `Feed.bout` but I'm not sure what to do.

I have also tried to run

```
read.zoo(file = "Av_Fe_Bout3.csv", format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

to try and change the format of `Feed.bout` however it just says

```
Error in read.csv.zoo(file = "Av_Fe_Bout3.csv", format = "%H:%M:%S") : 
  could not find function "read.csv.zoo"
```

Comment: I can sense a number of issues here. Your outcome is probably not coded as numeric or a factor (as the error says) and you haven't scaled your predictors, which as the error once again says, you will have issues with running interactions with different scales in `lme4`.

Comment: Its hard to help though without reproducible data. Run `dput(Feedbout)` and paste the output into your question so people can actually check out your data and help.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to emulate what you've done, but here I will provide a worked example using a binary dataset to show you what I imagine may be the issue. First, I will load the requisite packages. Then I will set a random seed so you can try what I have here (and hopefully on your own data).

```
#### Load Libraries and Random Seed ####
library(lmerTest)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
```

From here, there is no need to convert the outcome into a factor or numeric value for this *specific dataset*, but here I do so just to show you how to do it. I also create a simulated value called `fake` to add to `lme4`'s Verbagg data, as there are no other numeric predictors in this dataset. As there are 7585 observations, I simulate as many below.

```
#### Convert Variable to Factor ####
VerbAgg <- VerbAgg %>% 
  mutate(r2 = factor(r2),
         fake = rnorm(n=7584))
```

Then I fit the model as always. In this case, I put the `scale` function around the two numeric predictors in the interaction term.The `nAGQ` argument is only run here to speed up the run, as this data is normally slow to fit.

```
#### Fit Data to Model ####
fit <- glmer(r2 
             ~ scale(Anger)*scale(fake)
             + (1|id) 
             + (1|item),
        family = binomial,
        data = VerbAgg,
        nAGQ=0L)
```

Finally from there you just summarize the model with `summary(fit)`, which gives you this:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive
  Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: r2 ~ scale(Anger) * scale(fake) + (1 | id) + (1 | item)
   Data: VerbAgg

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  8203.1   8244.7  -4095.5   8191.1     7578 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.8761 -0.6234 -0.1787  0.6240 14.0824 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 1.815    1.347   
 item   (Intercept) 1.275    1.129   
Number of obs: 7584, groups:  id, 316; item, 24

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)              -0.155244   0.244350  -0.635  0.52521   
scale(Anger)              0.261487   0.081500   3.208  0.00133 **
scale(fake)               0.001112   0.028515   0.039  0.96890   
scale(Anger):scale(fake)  0.026135   0.029000   0.901  0.36747   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) scl(A) scl(f)
scale(Angr)  0.000              
scale(fake)  0.002 -0.003       
scl(Ang):() -0.001  0.011  0.001
```